# CSRF and CORS: Why allow the request to happen if we know there will be a cors error?

Tags: express, cors, csrf

I am confused by why the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package allows the request to be processed even if the origin in the request header isn't white-listed. For example, `res.status(202).send(await User.find())` returns a response with status code 202, but the data can't be loaded in the Chrome console.

Also, doesn't the browser send preflight OPTIONS requests to know what's allowed; why would it send cookies/credentials along a request with a disallowed origin?

Edit: [Tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74933041/understanding-preflight-requests?noredirect=1) a post request on jsfiddle and the post request doesn't happen server side. When I said "why the cors package allows" it would be better to say why the browser allows.

Comment: CORS is enforced by the client based on the rules sent to it by the server. It's possible to make a request otherwise prohibited by CORS in compliant user agents in an "opaque" manner which disallows access to the response body as a mitigation for XSS attacks on clients. It will still send cookies/etc. to ensure that even an opaque request can be authenticated. You seem to be under the impression that CORS provides some sort of security for the server - **it does not, and should not be relied on as such**.

Comment: @esqew Mostly correct, but XSS has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @jub0bs Yes, you’re right - wrote that comment a bit too quickly. Thanks for pointing out that inaccuracy - cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is enforced in the browser, not in your server. The server participates in setting headers that the browser can then use to determine whether the request should be allowed or not.  But, it is the browser that ultimately decides whether the CORS request satisfies the requirements or not and the result should be passed through to the Javascript in the browser.

Thus, the request is sent to the server, response is received and THEN the browser decides whether the Javascript in the page is allowed to see the result or not.

In some cases where the request is likely to have side effects on the server (based on a set of criteria in the request), the browser will send a pre-flight request to get just the CORS info first.

Comment: The "S" in CORS stands for "sharing"; it deserves to be capitalised as much as the first three letters :)

Comment: @jub0bs - Fair enough.